# jQuery code working in Chrome - Not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

I'm having an issue with my jQuery (jquery-1.12.4) code in Safari, but not in Chrome. When the form is submitted, the switch default action is called when using Safari. The code works as expected in Chrome. No errors appear in the developer console, only `Notice: No submit action detected!` is logged.

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
  // check acal-position-container for children
  if($('.acal-position-container').has('div').length < 1){
    alert("You cannot submit an empty form.\n\nIf you want to delete the current day, use the Delete button without removing any current positions.");
    return false;
  }

  // create the form_action post variable to decide what post action will be executed on the server
  var form_action = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "submit_type");
  // unset any old action properties (in case of a cancelled user action)
  $('form').append($(form_action).val(''));
  // confirm various actions
  switch ( $('button:focus').val() ) {
    case 'delete':
      $('form').append($(form_action).val('delete'));
      return confirm("Delete all positions for this day?");
    case 'publish':
      $('form').append($(form_action).val('publish'));
      return confirm("Publish all positions for this day?");
    case 'draft':
      $('form').append($(form_action).val('draft'));
      return confirm("Save all positions for this day as a draft?");
    default:
      console.log('Notice: No submit action detected!');
  }

});
```

The html

```
<button name="submit" type="submit" value="draft" class="acal-confirm" title="Do not make available publically">Save draft</button>
<button name="submit" type="submit" value="publish" class="acal-confirm" title="Save and publish the positions publically">Publish</button>
<button name="submit" type="submit" value="delete" class="acal-confirm" title="Delete the positions for this day">Delete day</button>
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Thanks.

**Edit:** As requested, more html

```
<form action="http://acal.dev/acal/calendar/project_positions/update_position/2/2" role="form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="running_day" value="1" style="display:none;" />
<input type="hidden" name="project_id" value="2" style="display:none;" />

<div class="form-inline pos-control-menu cal-card-hover">
  <h2>Project: Test</h2>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label style="margin-right:10px;">Select day</label>
    <select  id="select_day" style="margin-right:10px;" class="form-control input-lg">
        <option value="1">Monday</option>
        <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="4">Thursday</option>
        <option value="5">Friday</option>
        <option value="6">Saturday</option>
        <option value="0">Sunday</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- Action buttons -->
  <button name="submit" type="submit" value="draft" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg acal-confirm" title="Do not make available publically">Save draft</button>
  <button name="submit" type="submit" value="publish" style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg acal-confirm" title="Save and publish the positions publically">Publish</button>
  <button name="submit" type="submit" value="delete" style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg acal-confirm" title="Delete the positions for this day">Delete day</button>
</div>

<!-- POSITION CARD CONTAINER -->
<div class="acal-position-container">
    <div class="acal-card-container">

  <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="5">
  <div class="acal-card cal-card-hover">
    <div style="text-align:right;margin-bottom:10px;">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="remove-position-card"><strong>Remove position </strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="title[]">Title (required)</label><input type="text" name="title[]" value="Monday&#039;s steps"  class="form-control" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="max_vol[]">Maximum participants needed</label><input type="number" name="max_vol[]" value="2" min="1" max="999" class="form-control"  />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="description[]">Description</label><textarea name="description[]" cols="40" rows="10"  style="height:100px;" class="form-control">The description...</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="add_position_card" style="margin-top:15px;" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" value="Add position">
</form>
```

Comment: Could you show more html?

Comment: My first guess would be that the button doesn't have focus for whatever reason. Have you checked if `$('button:focus')` even returns anything in Safari?

Comment: You are right, running `$('button:focus')` in the console returns `[]` in Safari and `[prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "button:focus"]` in Chrome. So why does this happen?

Comment: Perhaps that calling the submit moves the focus to the form that was submitted in that specific browser. Again just guessing though.

Comment: Anyway, now that you know this you can think of a solution. You could create a `checkForm` function and bind this to the click of each button. This way you know which button was clicked. Then do your stuff for handling the form data and at the end of that function submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @vi5ion for the idea of calling a function on the submit button click. Here is the code I used.

```
/* Submit form event 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
$('button[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    // check if any positions exist (ie, user has not removed all the positions)
    $("form").submit(function (event) {
        // check acal-position-container for children
        if($('.acal-position-container').has('div').length < 1){
            alert("You cannot submit an empty form.\n\nIf you want to delete the current day, use the Delete button without removing any current positions.");
            //event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // create the form_action post variable to decide what post action will be executed on the server
    var form_action = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "submit_type");
    // unset any old action properties (in case of a cancelled user action)
    $('form').append($(form_action).val(''));
    // confirm various actions
    switch ( this.value ) {
        case 'delete':
            $('form').append($(form_action).val('delete'));
            return confirm("Delete all positions for this day?");
        case 'publish':
            $('form').append($(form_action).val('publish'));
            return confirm("Publish all positions for this day?");
        case 'draft':
            $('form').append($(form_action).val('draft'));
            return confirm("Save all positions for this day as a draft?");
        default:
            console.log('Notice: No submit action detected!');
    }

});
```